# How to prevent tikzDevice from scales font size for multi panel plots

Tags: r, plot, tikz

For multi panel plots obtained through `mfrow` or `layout`, `tikzDevice` scales the font when I have more than 3 subplots. Is there a possibility to avoid this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
tikz("fontsize-normal.tikz", width=5, height=2)
plot(1, xlab="my text")
dev.off()

tikz("fontsize-small.tikz", width=5, height=6)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(1, xlab="my text")
plot(1, xlab="my text")
plot(1, xlab="my text")
dev.off()
```

In the resulting .tikz-Code for the first plot the text-scaling is fine

```
\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.00]
at (192.68, 15.60) {my text};
```

In the second plot it scaled the node size

```
\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.66]
at (188.60,299.38) {my text};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Even though a little late, `par(mfrow=c(3,1), cex=1)` should to the trick.

As you use `par` with the `mfrow` argument, the scaling (`cex` in R) does not equal the defaul value of 1.

> "*cex* - A numerical value giving the amount by which plotting text and symbols should be magnified relative to the default. This starts as 1 when a device is opened, and **is reset** when the layout is changed, e.g. by setting ***mfrow***."
>   (check `?par` in R or [look here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html))

Comment: could you explain your Answer a bit more detailed? i do try to solve  the same problem using your idea and i am not sucessfull doing this